# Control mplayer with slave mode, key_down_event problem

Tags: mplayer

I'm trying to control mplayer through the slave mode with a fifo, some commands as

```
echo "pt_step 1" >> fifo
echo "quit" >> fifo
echo "pause" >> fifo
echo "set_property volume 60" > fifo
```

Work perfectly but the key_down_event doesn't

```
echo "key_down_event DOWN" >> fifo
echo "key_down_event UP" >> fifo
echo "key_down_event <-" >> fifo
echo "key_down_event ->" >> fifo
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to send numeric keycodes to mplayer. For instance,

```
echo 'key_down_event 100' > /path/to/fifo
```

will toggle framedropping (the "d" key, 0x64 in hexadecimal). I found this by accident, but `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` (and also xev which is hard to read though) will show the keycodes in hexadecimal, which you can convert to decimal e.g with galculator.

Comment: Wow, thanks for registering and answering!! Whenever I have time I´ĺl check it out

Comment: Your solution worked! the only problem was that I don't have the keysymdef.h file and xev showed the wrong keycodes :S.

The solution was to make a loop writing to the fifo till I found the correct values